# Enviar dados por Ajax, fazer MySQL query em background e plotar Google chart com os dados encontrados

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-charts

A seguir apresento um passo-a-passo do que o código que apresentarei já realiza corretamente.

Depois disso apresentarei a nova abordagem que gostaria de utilizar, mas que infelizmente nao está funcionando.

Em primeiro lugar (1) enviam-se dados através de um simples formulário;
(2) faz-se uma query no banco de dados MySQL;
(3) trata-se o array resultante [para economizar tempo e espaco esses dois últimos passos nao serao explicitamente demonstrados];
(4) retorna-se uma variável no formato correto a ser utilizado no Google Chart;
(5) redireciona-se para a página original (index.php);
(6) carrega-se novamente o index.php com o gráfico plotado.

Segue os códigos das páginas:

index.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
              function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Área de Conhecimento', 'Quantidade'],
                    <?php echo $_SESSION['chart']; ?>
                ]);
                var options = {
                  title: 'Áreas de Conhecimento'
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('areas'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
              }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="chart.php" id="form" method="post" role="form">
            <input id="pub-nr" name="pub-nr" placeholder="Publication Number" type="text" value="" required />
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['chart'])){
                echo '<div id="areas"></div>';
                unset($_SESSION['chart']);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

chart.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Query no banco de dados. Tratamento no array resultante até receber a variável abaixo:
    // Esses passos nao sao demonstrados aqui por nao serem essenciais para a solucao do problema.

    $chart = "['Ciências Humanas', 8],
              ['Ciências Sociais', 6],
              ['Filosofia',  4],
              ['Política', 2],
              ['Retórica', 1]";

    $_SESSION['chart'] = $chart;

    // Redirecionamento de volta para index.php
    header('Location: index.php');
```

Vale a pena ressaltar que dessa forma tudo funciona como esperado.

Agora o problema: Seguindo as melhores práticas para o desenvolvimento web, eu gostaria de realizar a mesma coisa descrita acima, mas com Ajax, para evitar que a página inteira seja recarregada.

Ajax é muito novo para mim e por isso estou enfrentando esses problemas.
Eu já li inúmeros posts na Internet, mas nao consegui fazer a "coisa" funcionar ainda e por isso conto com a ajuda de vocês.

O que me levou mais perto do eu gostaria de ter foi o seguinte post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729526/ajax-and-google-charts-passing-php

Mas ainda assim eu encontro problemas.

novo_index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" id="form" method="post" role="form">
            <input id="pub-nr" name="pub-nr" placeholder="Publication Number" type="text" value="" required />
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
        <div id="ajax"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('form#form').submit(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'chart.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $('form#form').serialize(),
                        success: function(response) {
                            $('div#ajax').html(response);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

novo_chart.php

```
<?php

    // Query no banco de dados. Tratamento no array resultante até receber a variável abaixo:
    // Esses passos nao sao demonstrados aqui por nao serem essenciais para a solucao do problema.

    $chart = "['Ciências Humanas', 8],
              ['Ciências Sociais', 6],
              ['Filosofia',  4],
              ['Política', 2],
              ['Retórica', 1]";

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
              function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    [\'Área de Conhecimento\', \'Quantidade\'],
                    <?php echo $chart; ?>
                ]);
                var options = {
                  title: \'Áreas de Conhecimento\'
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(\'areas\'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
              }
        </script>
        <div id="area"></div>';
```

Um tanto inortodoxo, mas foi o melhor que eu pude fazer com meus parcos conhecimentos na área. Como se vê, nao sao suficientes. :-)

Por isso a pergunta: o que eu teria que modificar nos códigos (originais) para que eu consiga imprimir o gráfico utilizando Ajax, i.é sem ter que recarregar a página? Por favor nao considere um conhecimento prévio elevado em Ajax e principalmente em json. Um exemplo funcional concreto seria muito bem vindo. ;-)

Muito obrigado de antemao pela ajuda.

Comment: Bem vinda ao site, [Heloisa](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heloísa_de_Argenteuil) :) Tem um passo importante no AJAX que é fazer com que seu `chart.php` funcione sozinho para gerar uma string ou array, que é o que vai ser devolvido pro JS para preencher o conteúdo desejado; uma vez funcionando sozinho, conectar ao JS. . . . Assim, olhando por cima, eu tentaria executar o script do google lá no `index.php` a partir de dados simplificados do AJAX.

Comment: Olá @brasofilo, obrigado por sua resposta! Estou aqui quebrando a cabeca e ainda nada... O chart.php parece que funciona sozinho sim. Se eu carregar só esse arquivo ele me dá a string esperada, se eu dou um 'echo'. O que eu nao estou conseguindo fazer é essa "devolucao" para o JS nem tampouco essa conexao ao JS. Aí você falou grego... :-) O problema de executar o script no index.php é que ele é carregado antes de eu executar a query que me dá justamente os dados para preencher o gráfico. Ou estou pensando errado?

Comment: PS: E obrigado pelas dicas. Aos poucos estou entendendo como se utiliza o site.

Comment: Na verdade, foram só algumas observações em forma de comentário; respostas propriamente ditas são publicadas abaixo. Não tenho condição de testar agora, nem nunca usei o  `google.visualization`, mas não entendo porquê está usando `$_SESSION`... E aquela função `drawChart()` no `index.php` não dá problema se `$_SESSION['char']` não estiver setado?

Comment: Olá brasofilo os 2 primeiros arquivos nao têm problemas e nao sao objeto da minha dúvida. O que eu fazia com eles é o seguinte: enviar dados de index.php para chart.php através do form do index.php. No chart.php é feita entao a query e a resultante final é uma string que eu insiro nessa variável da session. Depois mandava tudo de volta para index.php e aí sim o drawChart() tinha os dados (que vinham pela $_SESSION['chart']) para desenhar o gráfico. Se essa variável nao estiver presente nao há problema algum. Apenas o gráfico nao será desenhado. Meu problema é como fazer o mesmo usando ajax.